# Ask budler not to upgrade a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am not able to run `bundle update devise` or `bundle install`

`$ bundle update devise`

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies............
Fetching rake 12.3.0 (was 10.1.0)
Installing rake 12.3.0 (was 10.1.0)
Gem::RuntimeRequirementNotMetError: rake requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0. The current ruby version is 1.9.1.
An error occurred while installing rake (12.3.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '12.3.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

and this is what I am getting on `$ bundle install`

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
You have requested:
  devise = 2.2.4

The bundle currently has devise locked at 3.1.0.
Try running `bundle update devise`

If you are updating multiple gems in your Gemfile at once,
try passing them all to `bundle update`
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you use an ancient ruby (v1.9.1) in the first place?

Comment: Can we see your gemfile as well?

Comment: @mudasobwa  I am working on an old app so there is nothing I can do about the ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

From the log trace given it seems like you have specified the version 2.2.4 in gemfile for devise.

Just remove the version from gemfile and then run bundle update, rubygems will itself find the dependent gem version based on the ruby version and lock it the gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 0):

The problem being that your Devise Gem is locked to a particular version which is the problem. If you check your `gemfile.lock` you will see its fixed.

Changing version in a Gemfile will not affect which gem version is loaded. bundle install / bundle update is actually needed.

Example of how you can go about that is in the Devise Gem [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started).

Change your gemfile to `gem 'devise'` and run `bundle install` rubygems will itself find the dependent gem version based on the ruby version and lock it to the gemfile.lock.